# How do I bind a gridview to a Generic list of strings?

Tags: gridview

This should be simple but I am losign this battle. I have a gridview. All I want is for the user to be able to enter names into it, click add and have the values added. I also want to use the delete command, should they make a mistake. I have tried Eval and Bind. But something keeps going wrong.

I have a textbox in the  to enter the first one. And alos a textbox in the footer to enter values. When they are entered, they are added to a generic list (string) and re-bound to the gridview. But it fails when it attempts to bind to the list.

In the markup below, DataItem.Alias <- Alias is actually the name of the generic list

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvAlias"
    runat="server"     
   ShowFooter="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="false"
   ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" ShowHeader="False" >
    <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Alias")%>  />
                </ItemTemplate>
               <FooterTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtFooterAlias"  runat="server" />
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnFooterAdd" runat="server"  OnClick="AddFromFooter">Add New</asp:LinkButton>
               </FooterTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True"   />
      </Columns>
      <EmptyDataTemplate>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmptyAlias" runat="server"   />
           <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEmptyAdd" runat="server" OnClick="AddFromEmpty">Add New</asp:LinkButton>
      </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

and the code behind...

Public Sub BindGridView()

```
Dim oThis As This 'this is a class I have that has a property which is a generic list of string

    gvAlias.DataSource = oThis.Alias.ToArray
    gvAlias.DataBind()
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you elaborate on "something keeps going wrong"?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, type of Alias is not clear. Is it a Anonymous type?

However very easy way to bind grid with List of string is by converting them to any time.

```
var aliasList = new List<string>() { 
               "Value1",
               "Value2",
               "Value3"
            };
//This will create new anonymous type with Name field.
var tryName = (from nm in nameList
                select new { Alias = nm }).ToArray();
gvAlias.DataSource = tryName;
gvAlias.DataBind();
```

Now you can bind this "Alias" field in your markup

```
<asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Alias")%>  />
                </ItemTemplate>
               <FooterTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtFooterAlias"  runat="server" />
                  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnFooterAdd" runat="server"  OnClick="AddFromFooter">Add New</asp:LinkButton>
               </FooterTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True"   />
```